# PHP data exchange between scripts - files are locked

Tags: php, ajax, performance

I'm running a long PHP script on the server which can take several minutes to finish so in the meantime I'd like to show the process to the user.

I start the long process with AJAX and I run a different AJAX request every 2 seconds which updates the progress in the browser.

In the long script I write the current state into a file and I'd like to read this value in the checking script.

My problem is : The checking script doesn't respond until the long process is finished because it waits for the file to be released.

However, I close the file every time.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not write the current progress to a session variable?

Comment: Please give your checking script.

Comment: How are you writing and reading the file? It's hard to diagnose this problem without more information. For example, `tail -f | grep` has a problem similar to this because `grep` is block buffered, so it is a *long* time before you see the output of `tail`. But that could also have nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: @hank: That’ll have exactly the same problem, at least with file-based session storage, because access to the session file will be blocked while the script is still using the session.

Comment: yeah, I tried using the session variables first, but it had the same problem, however I used the session_write_close function and started the session again.

Comment: in the checking script I just open the file with file_get_contents and   write it to the output